# my JavaScript script is not gonna echo in php

Tags: javascript, php, sql

i have a ads script which i stored in my database using textarea field. but when i echo that script in php. then it will not working. 
this is my script which i saved in database by using textarea field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ( function() {
  if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) { window.CHITIKA = { 'units' : [] }; };
  var unit = {"calltype":"async[2]","publisher":"seeknfameads","width":300,"height":250,"sid":"Chitika Default","color_site_link":"337ab7","color_text":"337ab7"};
  var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
  window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
  document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
  }());
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.chitika.net/getads.js" async></script>
```

And when i fetch field and try to echo this. it is not working.

```
  $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
            $query4 = $conn->query($sql4);
            $row4 = $query4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $video_des=$row4['video_des'];
            $rowc = $query4->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($rowc>=1){
            <script><?php echo $video_des;?></script>
            }
```

please help to fix this problem.

Comment: did you save your script with the <script> tag or without <script> tag?

Comment: then why you are echoing your script in <script> tag

Comment: i got this point buddy. thanks without <script> now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already inserting value of video_des with `<script> and </script>` tag

You don't need to add `<script>` tag again, Please try below.

```
 $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $query4 = $conn->query($sql4);
        $row4 = $query4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $video_des=$row4['video_des'];
        $rowc = $query4->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($rowc>=1){
          echo $video_des;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this at your if condition result

```
if ($rowc>=1){
         echo $video_des; // remove script tag from here
}
```